# Accordion Control not found in toolbox

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've installed Silverlight 4 and its toolkit. 
But i cant find the controls in the toolkit.
my installation is correct. I want to  add accordion control to my page. but that is not in the toolbox. i tried choose items. but there is no accordion control. how do i add the reference of the toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and there are not really any great resources to help with this.

Anyhow, you need to install the Silverlight **Toolkit**, not just the SDK.  Once the toolkit is installed, the Accordion control should show up in your toolbox.  It did for me.